# Determine file age in days

Tags: java

Given a `Path`, I would like to determine the file's age based on last modified time. I know how to get the last modified time:

```
FileTime t = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
```

I also know how to get the current date/time with:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
```

However, I failed to see any connection between the two. I imagine I have to convert from one type to anther, then calculate the diff in days, but I am stuck at reading the documentation at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wouldn't use `LocalDate.now()` - that depends on your current time zone. A file's age in days of *elapsed* time can be computed in a time zone neutral manner.

Instead, convert the `FileTime` to an `Instant` via `toInstant`, and then you can find the duration:

```
Instant fileInstant = t.toInstant();
Instant now = clock.instant(); // Where clock is a java.time.Clock, for testability
Duration difference = Duration.between(fileInstant, now);
long days = difference.toDays();
```

Comment: Dumb question: How do I create an object of type `java.time.Clock`t

Comment: @HaiVu: See the docs for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html which show various static methods which return a `Clock`.

Comment: I saw that and thought `Clock.systemUTC()` would be the ideal choice, but not too sure about that.

Comment: I also read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/clock.html

Comment: @HaiVu: If you're not relying on the time zone of the clock (which we're not here) then `systemUTC` is absolutely fine. But I'd use dependency injection and inversion of control so that production uses that, and testing uses a fake clock.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`toMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toMillis--) method in [`FileTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html):

```
long ft = t.toMillis();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = ft - now; // diff in milliseconds
```

Comment: Note that by using `System.currentTimeMillis()` this code is harder to test than code using a `java.time.Clock` which can be injected with a system clock for production and a fake clock for testing.

Comment: Just because this answer is in competition with Jon Skeet's and there is a comment by him about the testing, does not mean this answer is incorrect. It is infact much useful because you change the date of system and verify weather the output is as desired. Jon Skeet's answer is getting these many upvotes because of his popularity and NOTHING ELSE.